# ZSH do not remeber github id

Tags: 18.04, git, zsh, github

I recently switched to `zsh` and `oh my zsh` and now every time i want to push in my github account, I have to give my username and password. It is not remembering it. Bash still remembers it. How to solve it?

Comment: Shells do _not_ remember passwords. Please check what program do you use to contact GitHub in each shell. If you don’t know how, please start with [edit]ing your question to show full commands you use in Bash and Zsh.

Comment: What is the output of `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in each shell?

Comment: output is `/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh`

Comment: @Melebius my commands were `git init` `git add -A` `git commit -m "SADSA"` `git remote add origin mylink.git` `git push -y origin master` and then it prompts my username and password for github. Whereas if i repeat/do same commands in bash, it automatically remembers my last if id & password and push it directly to that account.